# How to format strings using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-requests

I have been given a string as shown below

```
s = 'This is sentence 1."This is sentence 2." This is sentence 3.'
```

I want the output as below

```
This is sentence 1.
"This is sentence 2."
This is sentence 3.
```

I have written following code for this

```
s = 'This is sentence 1."This is sentence 2." This is sentence 3.'
for i in s.replace('.','.\n').split('\n'):
  print(i.strip())
```

And below is the output I got

```
This is sentence 1.
"This is sentence 2.
" This is sentence 3.
```

The problem is with a double quoted sentence.

I think something can be done with regex, if I can write a regex which can distinguish between . and ." then I can solve my problem.

Comment: Your problem is unclear. Why can’t you ignore the input ‘s’ and just have output=‘This is sentence 1.\n”This. .... ‘ ?

Comment: I am thinking to do something with regular expression. If a regular expression can be written which will replace a '.' with '.\n' and '."' with '."\n" then problem will be solved.

Comment: try this `print('\n'.join(re.findall('\"[\w ]+\.\"|[\w ]+\.', s)))`

Answer (score 0):

If this is the exact case that you need to solve, the following code will do it:

```
import re

s = 'This is sentence 1."This is sentence 2." This is sentence 3.'

output = re.findall("This.is.sentence.\d.", s)
output[1] = '"' + output[1] + '"'
for i in range(0, len(output)):
    print(output[i])
```

Otherwise, a different method would need to be used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just gave some dummy sentence, the actual requirement has news articles given in the single string and requirement is to break each sentence in different line. I will try to modify the code suggested by you.

Comment: I'm surprised that the news articles would not have a space between a `.` and the next sentence, like in the example `This is sentence 1."This is `

Answer (score 0):

I will try to give you a hint. try adding an **IF statement** to let your code decide what to do what you want to do exactly. This in case you want to use your code with a larger string.

Answer (score 0):

Solving this for a general case (any number of sentences, of which any number can be quoted) is actualy quite complicated, especially if double quotes can occur not only around, but also within sentences. I think this code works, but I am not completely satisified with it:

```
import re

s = 'Some sentence. Another sentence. "A quoted sentence." A "sentence" containing quotes. Yet another sentence.'

rx = re.compile(r'"[^"]+?\."\s*|[^"].+?\.\s*')
r = re.match(rx, s)
while r:
   print(r.group(0))
   s = re.sub(rx, '', s, 1)
   r = re.match(rx, s)
```